# SVN admin run out space in tmp

Tags: debian, svn

I'm trying to run **svnadmin pack** on a large repo that lives in an SSD that have enough space. But svnadmin using system /tmp folder. /tmp lives in a root partition and only got 2 GB left. So operation exit with no space left error.

Packing revisions in shard 0...svnadmin: E000028: Can't write to file '/tmp/svn-ifZTVJ': No space left on device

Q1 Is there a way to tell svnadmin to use a different folder for temp files?

if not,

I have enough space and I can create a new partition. If I create a new partition how should I point system tmp to the new partition?

Comment: You could try to set a different TMP directory with`TMP=<full-path-to-new-tmp> svadmin pack ...`, which will be valid for the single execution of `svnadmin`. Or you could `export TMP=<full-path-to-new-tmp> ` which is valid until the shell is closed.

Comment: tried this and it didn't work. when i try $TMPDIR or $TMP it is returns empty. according to google its the default env variable for temp dir. Im in Debian OS

Comment: @Thomas: I suggest you add your reply as an answer. I can confirm it works as you describe. Yasantha: keep in mind that the TMP variable is not set by default, you would need to set it temporarily as Thomas described.